# What is the maximum work inequality?

Tags: classical-mechanics

In the Springer Handbook of Robotics, under the section dealing with manipulation, specifically friction limit surface, there's the following sentence.

> When the part slips on the support, the contact wrench $\omega$ lies on the limit surface, and by the **maximum-work inequality**, the twist $t$ is normal to the limit surface at $\omega$

([here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=Xpgi5gSuBxsC&pg=PA662&lpg=PA662&dq=springer+handbook+of+robotics+maximum+work+inequality&source=bl&ots=lVooR5k50V&sig=ACfU3U2GpaJvegiFy3CwbU653cVXR0qtmA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC2urw94npAhVaXSsKHVlHANkQ6AEwAnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=springer%20handbook%20of%20robotics%20maximum%20work%20inequality&f=false))

The closest I found was [this wikipedia page on Principle of maximum work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_work#Thermodynamics) but it seems to relate to chemical reactions, and I couldn't quite relate the two.

So what is the maximum-work inequality (and how does that let us conclude that the twist is normal to the limit surface at the given contact wrench)?

Answer (score -1):

From [1] Drucker's maximum work theorem states

> [...] A material on which an external agency does positive work during
>   an elastic-plastic stress cycle is considered strain hardening. As the inequality will
>   not be satisfied if the material is strain softening, the postulate is often referred
>   to as Drucker’s strain hardening postulate. To a close approximation the net plastic
>   work done over the loading part of the cycle can be expressed as:
>
> $$(\sigma_{ij}-\sigma_{ij}^{\circ})d\epsilon_{ij}^p + \frac{1}{2} d\sigma_{ij}d\epsilon_{ij}^p > 0 \tag{21}\label{1}$$
>
> Drucker’s first and second postulate follows from this inequality. If it is
>   assumed that the original state of stress is one of yielding, the first term cancels.
>   In accordance with the inequality, the first postulate states that the plastic work
>   done by an external agency during the application of additional stress is positive
>   for a work hardening and zero for a non-hardening material. If the last part of
>   the postulate is to be true, vectors representing the increments of stress and plastic
>   strain have to be perpendicular. In a non-hardening material loading is assumed to be neutral, that is all load paths are tangential to the yield surface. Therefore the
>   increment of strain is directed normally to it, thus resulting in the normality law.
>   If the material is hardening, it must be assumed that the increment of stress is a
>   linear combination of a plastic and an elastic part, and that the last is directed
>   tangentially to the yield surface. As the elastic part of the stress increment does
>   no irreversible work, the increment of plastic strain is also in this case directed normal
>   to the yield surface.
>
> Drucker’s second postulate is connected to the first part of the inequality above
>   and states that the net work done by an external agency during a cycle of addition
>   and removal of stresses is non-negative. If it is assumed that the original state
>   of stress is not one of yielding, the last term in the inequality can be neglected.
>   The result is:
>
> $$(\sigma_{ij}-\sigma_{ij}^{\circ})d\epsilon_{ij}^p \ge 0 \tag{22}\label{2}$$

According to Callen [2]

> 4-5 THE MAXIMUM WORK THEOREM
>
> The propensity of physical systems to increase their entropy can be
>   channeled to deliver useful work. All such applications are governed by
>   the maximum work theorem.
>
> Consider a system that is to be taken from a specified initial state to a
>   specified final state. Also available are two auxiliary systems, into one of
>   which work can be transferred, and into the other of which heat can be
>   transferred. *Then the maximum work theorem states that for all processes
>   leading from the specified initial state to the specified final state of the
>   primary system, the delivery of work is maximum (and the delivery of heat is
>   minimum) for a reversible process. Furthermore the delivery of work (and
>   of heat) is identical for every reversible process.*

[1]: Totten, Mackenzie: Handbook of Aluminum Volume 1 Physical Metallurgy and Processes, page 433-434

[2]: Callen: THERMODYNAMICS AND AN INTRODUCTION TO THERMOSTATISTICS 3rd ed, page 103